# Hiding Control Attributes in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, attributes, composite-controls

I am building a composite control that is composed of an Infragistics WebDataGrid, an add Button, and some ModalPopupExtenders. I want design-time usage of this composite control to be as simple as possible. Meaning, as soon as they type not want there to be any AccessKey, EnableTheming, and all of those completely irrelevant properties to even show up when designing this control.

Bottom line: Anyone know how to hide an attribute in a custom control?

Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can override all the properties and put a Browsable attribute on them:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public override string AccessKey
{
    get
    {
        return base.AccessKey;
    }
    set
    {
        base.AccessKey = value;
    }
}
```